# populate textbox and picture box when row in listview selected

Tags: vb.net

Hi i'm currently developing a system(vb.Net). here's the scenario, i a have textbox, picture box and a listview, where when i click  a row from the listview it will populate the textbox and a picture box(e.g Users Details and her/his ID picture), but when i click the next row, only the textbox will change its value but the image on picturebox will not change.. here's my partially working code:

```
Try
    If lvUsrProf.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        ''Call userImage()
        Dim adptr As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim tbl As DataTable
        Dim commbuild As MySqlCommandBuilder
        'Dim uID As Integer

        adptr.SelectCommand = cmd
        tbl = New DataTable
        adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT  pic_image FROM userprofile", uCon)
        commbuild = New MySqlCommandBuilder(adptr)
        adptr.Fill(tbl)
        Dim lb() As Byte = tbl.Rows(0).Item("pic_image")
        Dim lstr As New System.IO.MemoryStream(lb)
        pboxID.Image = Image.FromStream(lstr)
        lstr.Close()

        txtIdNo.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        txtName.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
        txtLstNam.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
        cboDept.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
        txtPOs.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        txtCont.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text
        txtEmail.Text = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text
        'pboxID.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    uCon.Close()
End Try
```

Your brilliant ideas and suggestions will be much appreciated!.. Maraming Salamat!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are fetching all images from the table userprofile. Then for every selection you make you select the first item in that result. This image will always be the same since you aren't using a where clause in your select. Try adding something like this:

```
WHERE ID = lvUsrProf.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
```

This should only fetch you one image and it should be the one connected to the selected account.